# Make a pad connect to two nets with different names in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad

I have a part that is an SMT 'jumper', it is unpopulated and you use it by bridging the pads with solder. I want to put a track from the pin pad to GND. But the pad pin needs to also go to an address pin on a controller. How do I do this in the schematic? I am currently just placing a track on the .BRD file, but this is hacky. The only other way I can think of is make it in the jumper part, again not ideal.

Comment: You mean one of the two pads is GND and the other one the connection to the controller? Something like an address-select via jumper-setting?

Answer (score 1):

Make the jumper be a part, and put it onto the schematic and PCB.

Sparkfun have already made some bridges. I think the one you are describing is called SOLDERJUMPERTRACE in my version of their library.

There are other bridges in SPARKFUN'S Eagle libraries, for example with a very narrow 'neck' of copper, so that it can be connected by default, and cut with a fine knife to remove the connection.

IMHO it seems less hacky to have a part, which encapsulates the behaviour, than arrange some tracks on the PCB that work that way. A proper part shows that it is really intended, and provides some documentation hints for future editors of the ECAD.